# WordPress editor Working fine in text mode but not in visual mode.Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i used `wp_editor` function to implement editor in a plugin.it is implemented but when i type some text(in visual mode) and hit save. it is not saving the value in options.php. but if i edit (in text mode) enter some text and then if i save at the time it is saving the value in options.php

Here is the sample code

```
 <?php
    $editor = get_option('message');
    $opt = array("textarea_name" => "message[textarea]");
    wp_editor( $editor['textarea'], "message[textarea]", $opt );
 ?>
```

Why it is saving the values if edit in text mode but not in visual mode? can anyone help?

**After Posting Question**

Another format i tried after posting this question Here too the same problem

Basic (with mandatory required feild)

```
 <?php 
      $content1 = get_option('val');
      $editor_id='val';  
      wp_editor( $content1, $editor_id );
 ?>
```

Comment: Try monitoring your browser javascript console via Firebug/equivalent and see if there are any javascript errors that would give more clues in regards to what's going wrong with the editor when you attempt to save in visual mode.

Comment: @pallandt Thanks. I tried but there is no bugs in console.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access atm to a WordPress env so I can't attempt to investigate more. Hopefully you are not running any security-related plugins in your WordPress development install. I'd try googling for similar issues if I were in your situation though, I'm sure it has happened to other people as well.

Comment: @pallandt i'm trying in google, tutorials where there but no issues like the same.here is the link for tutor http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-using-wp_editor/  i'm searching.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all of your plugins, and then re-activate them one by one testing after each activation. I had this issue a while ago, and took me forever to work out.